# Is there a more efficient way of doing function 'which' in R?

Tags: performance, r

The data file is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6u0ktUDM9nGc3ZNTXVZN2kwRVB4VFM4amVmc2ppZjE4aWlr).

Here are my codes:

```
> ftable=read.table(file.choose())
> start.time=Sys.time()
> 1-length(which(ftable==1))/sum(ftable)
[1] 0.12
> end.time=Sys.time()
> end.time-start.time
Time difference of 0.004880905 secs
```

I understand that 0.00488 secs are not a lot. But I have to repeatedly do this calculation over different and larger tables. I am wondering if the function '`which`' can be replaced by a more efficient one.

Thanks in advance!

Note: This piece of codes is to calculate the percentage of singletons in ftable. If there is a more efficient way, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Is dividing by `sum(df)` really what you want to calculate the "percentage of singletons"? Or do you rather need something along the lines of `prop.table(table(unlist(df, use.names = FALSE)))`?

Comment: For measuring computation times, you can wrap some code inside `system.time({})`. However, when measuring such short computation times like yours, that approach or yours are not good at all: instead of one execution, you want to run the code many, many times and look at the median computation time. There is a package that does that well: `microbenchmark`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
1-sum(ftable==1L)/sum(ftable)
```

Test on larger data:

```
n <- 1000000
set.seed(21)
ftable <- data.frame(replicate(3, sample.int(4, n, replace = T))-1L)

start.time=Sys.time()
1-length(which(ftable==1))/sum(ftable)
end.time=Sys.time()
end.time-start.time
# Time difference of 0.1981359 secs

start.time=Sys.time()
1-sum(ftable==1L)/sum(ftable)
end.time=Sys.time()
end.time-start.time
# Time difference of 0.06704712 secs
```

bechmarks:

```
n <- 1000000
set.seed(21)
ftable <- data.frame(replicate(3, sample.int(4, n, replace = T))-1L)

jz <- function() 1-length(which(ftable==1))/sum(ftable)  
minem <- function() 1-sum(ftable==1L)/sum(ftable)

br <- bench::mark(jz(), minem(), iterations = 50)
br[, 1:7]
# A tibble: 2 x 7
#   expression      min     mean   median      max `itr/sec` mem_alloc
#   <chr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
# 1 jz()         51.2ms   53.8ms   52.6ms   66.3ms      18.6    60.1MB
# 2 minem()      37.7ms   39.9ms   38.5ms     67ms      25.1    45.8MB
# only around 36 % faster
```

Comment: as it's a percentage `1-mean(ftable==1L)` will be enough